# MPAndroidChart -get the value of x entry

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I want to get the values for the x entry which is a string when clicked on a sector of pie. how? I can get y value using getVal(), but how about x? The value for x axis entry is from sqlite. The code are as shown below

```
public class chart extends Activity {

private FrameLayout chartContainer;
private PieChart mChart;

Context CTX = this;
DatabaseOperations DOP;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chart);
    chartContainer=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.chartContainer);
    mChart=new PieChart(this);
    //add pie chart to the layout
    chartContainer.addView(mChart);

    //enable hole and configure
    mChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
    mChart.setHoleColorTransparent(true);

    mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {                if (e == null)
                return;
            Toast.makeText(chart.this, xVals.get(e.getXIndex()) + " used " + e.getVal() + "kwh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() {

        }
    });

    //add data
    addeachData();

    Legend l=mChart.getLegend();
    l.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.RIGHT_OF_CHART);
}

protected void addeachData() {
    DatabaseOperations DOP = new DatabaseOperations(CTX);
    Cursor CR = DOP.getInformation(DOP);
    int count=CR.getCount();

    float[]values=new float[count];
    String[]name=new String[count];

    for (int m=0; m<count; m++){
        CR.moveToNext();
        name[m]=CR.getString(0);
        values[m]=CR.getFloat(1);
    }
    ArrayList<Entry> yVals = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    for (int i = 0; i <name.length; i++)
        yVals.add(new Entry(values[i], i));

    final ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i <name.length; i++)
        xVals.add(name[i]);

    ArrayList<Integer> colors=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int c: ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);
    colors.add(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
    dataSet.setColors(colors);

    PieData data=new PieData(xVals, dataSet);
    data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
    data.setValueTextSize(11f);
    data.setValueTextColor(Color.GRAY);

    mChart.setData(data);
    mChart.highlightValues(null);
    mChart.invalidate();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At fist you declared an ArrayList like "xVals" for holding x axis values. Change it to final so it will be accessible from inner classes.

```
final ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then use getXIndex() method from entry object. For example:

```
xVals.get(entry.getXIndex());
```

Comment: i cant access the xVal, i updated my code. Can you help me with it? thank you

Comment: I put the declaration of xvals up with the context and database and it worked now. thank you